# Wpf adding stack panels from view

Tags: wpf

I'm not sure my title is clear (poor wpf skills).

What i'm trying to do is to create a smart data entry form. My goal is to have a hard coded data that the user should enter, and on demand (a plus button) he can enter another set of data, every time the user will click the plus button another set will appear in the window (endless)

Edit:

For more details, for a very simple example of what i'm trying to achieve, lets say that this is the window:

[image]

And after the user will click the plus button the window will look like this:

[image]

And the plus button will always let the user adding more peoples.

Comment: Your question is unclear; can you post a picture or XAML? Do you have code? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope this will make it more clear.

Comment: @DourHighArch I don't have code yet, i'm trying to figure out the design i need for my xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like all you need is a List and a ItemControl:

Your Model:

```
  public class User 
  {
      public String Name { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
  }
```

In your ViewModel:

```
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }

   //In your constructor
   Users  = new List<User>();
```

In your View:

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Users}>
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                 <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
              </StackPanel>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                 <TextBlock Text="Age:" />
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
              </StackPanel>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

And then below this wire up your add button to a command to point to a method that would do someething like:

```
    private void AddUser()
    {
       Users.Add(new User());
       NotifyPropertyChange("Users");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like the answer to my question, but just one more thing. My application is more complicated than the simple example i gave earlier, and my model does not have a constructor with no parameters, so how can i overcome that?

Comment: What kind of parameters does your model take?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ItemsControl` with its `ItemsSource` property bound to a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person>`, where Person is a class holding the name and age as strings.

(1) Create Person

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

(2) Create PeopleViewModel, holding your collection.

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> People { get; private set; }

    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person>(_people);          

        addPerson(); // adding the 1st person
    }

    // You also need to hook this up to the button press somehow
    private void addPerson()
    {
        _people.Add(new Person());
    }
}
```

(3) Set the `DataContext` of your window to be a PersonViewModel in the code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PeopleViewModel();
    }
}
```

(4) Create an `ItemsControl` along with a `DataTemplate` for Person

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="name:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                 </StackPanel>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="age:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Don't forget to hook up your button either through a `Command` or through the `Button.Click` event.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like the answer to my question, but just one more thing. My application is more complicated than the simple example i gave earlier, and my model does not have a constructor with no parameters, so how can i overcome that?

Comment: I need more information to understand the issue you are having. Why can't you just pass parameters to the constructor?